# angular 2+ component with attribute name and no parameters

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-class

I want to allow a user to provide a list of one-word attributes without parameter values. For example,

```
<container row crosscenter wrap spacearound ...>
```

which results in something like this in container.html

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'flexDisplay': true, 'directionRow': isRow, 'directionCol': isCol, 'contentSpaceAround': isSpaceAround}" ...>
```

What I'm missing is how to set

```
@Input('row') isRow = false;
```

to true if 'row' was present in the container line.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.
Yogi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be handled in `ngOnChanges`. The value can be assigned either back to input property or to some object that will be passed to ngClass

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if ('foo' in changes) {
    this.options.foo = true;
  }
}
```

Since there's no way how inputs can become unassigned, there's no reason to provide bindings for them. `@Attribute` can be used instead:

```
constructor(@Attribute('foo') public foo: boolean|null) {
  this.foo = (foo != null);
}
```

Using attributes for regular options isn't a good decision, design-wise. This prevents from setting them dynamically. Instead, it is always preferable to accept options input. If all options are supposed to be flags, it can be a string input that will be split and processed in `ngOnChanges`, like:

```
<container options="row crosscenter wrap spacearound">
```

or

```
<container [options]="'row crosscenter wrap spacearound'">
```

Comment: I like your answer.  In particular using the options = approach.  The thing I don't understand is how this will cause and onChanges event to occur.  Can you help me understand that?

Comment: Changes in @Input prop are handled with https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges hook. If you set component `options` input, the value can be watched in ngOnChanges hook. It will run at least once with initial `options` value.

Comment: Thanks estus.  I think the thing that really made this the right answer is the fact that it does run at least once with the initial options.  I appreciate your help.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to my question is to create directives for each of the "one-word" tags (attributes) I want to use.
:-)